# How do you change the text color in the statusbar in MFMailComposeViewController using Swift

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm trying to change the text color in the status bar to match the rest of the apps appearance. I can change the text color in the nav bar for the MFMailComposeViewController easily enough:

```
myEmailComposerViewConotroller.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Am I missing something in the API on changing the text color of the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, I think you're going to want to do something like this:

```
myEmailComposerViewConotroller.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

`titleTextAttributes` is of type `[NSObject: AnyObject]?`

so that is why we initialize it to:

```
[NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Comment: I'm actually looking to change the text color on the Status Bar, not the navigation bar. The snippet I posted above actually sets the navigation bar text tint to white including the cancel and send buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I already answered sth similar here: [how to change statusbar color in one view controller using swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062162/how-to-change-statusbar-color-in-one-view-controller-using-swift/35062587#35062587)

Set `View controller-based status bar appearance` in your project.plist to **NO**

Subclass the `MFMailViewController` and implement custom `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` functions

Use `viewWillAppear` and will `viewWillDisappear` to set and reset the statusBarStyle, while keeping a property with the previous statusBarStyle like this

```
let initialStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle

func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    initialStatusBarStyle = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(.LightContent, animated: animated)
}

func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(initialStatusBarStyle, animated: animated)
}
```