# how to change statusbar color in one view controller using swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
```

I use this one to change status bar to light in all app. But now I need to change it in just one View Controller back to black. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the Status Bar Color for specific ViewControllers using Swift in iOS8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956728/changing-the-status-bar-color-for-specific-viewcontrollers-using-swift-in-ios8)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set `View controller-based status bar appearance` in your project.plist to **NO**

Use `viewWillAppear` and will `viewWillDisappear` to set and reset the statusBarStyle, while keeping a property with the previous statusBarStyle like this

```
let initialStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle

func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    initialStatusBarStyle = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(.LightContent, animated: animated)
}

func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(initialStatusBarStyle, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: Hmm, but it should. what is going

Comment: It was my mistake. I missed your phrase "Set View controller-based status bar appearance in your project.plist to NO". Now it works. Thank You!

Comment: Glad it worked out, you might want to mark your question as answered then

Comment: @MarkHim when I use this and switch between two VC using tabbed navigation it doesnt work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546787/swift-ios-trying-to-change-color-of-status-bar-on-certain-vcs

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle(initialStatusBarStyle, animated: true)` was deprecated in iOS 9. You might want to update your code. Use `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = initialStatusBarStyle `.

Answer (score 13):

## Xcode 8.1, Swift 3 Solution with @IBDesignable

This solution is a little bit different:

- Subclass of UIViewController to centralize logic
- No code for viewDidLoad or viewDidDisappear
- Uses @IBDesignable so you can set your status bar color in the Attributes Inspector on the Storyboard

### Step 1 - Setup Info.plist File

[image: Info.plist]

### Step 2 - Subclass UIViewController

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class DesignableViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBInspectable var LightStatusBar: Bool = false

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        get {
            if LightStatusBar {
                return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
            } else {
                return UIStatusBarStyle.default
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Step 3 - Inherit from DesignableViewController

Change the code for your ViewController(s) from:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

To:

```
class ViewController: DesignableViewController {
```

### Step 4 - Set your preference on the Storyboard

Select the ViewControllers on the Storyboard and go to the Attributes Inspector:
[image: Attributes Inspector]

### Step 5 - Run project and test

In my project I setup a Tab Bar Controller with 2 View Controllers and switch back and forth between the two. Seems to work OK for me.
[image: Light Status Bar]
[image: Dark Status Bar]

Comment: This is brilliant! Wonderful solution.

Answer (score 8):

**Solved:

Swift 3.1**

Just using this code in View Controller:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! The autocomplete does not show this since it's a var, but it works 100%!

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

Set View controller-based status bar appearance in your project.plist to NO

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle(.default, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle(.lightContent, animated: animated)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `Objective-C` answer:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let color = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.60, blue:0.48,alpha:1.0)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blue
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = color
```

**OR**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```

Answer (score 0):

In swit4 this working fine in my project based on navigation bar

```
   let app = UIApplication.shared
   let statusBarHeight: CGFloat = app.statusBarFrame.size.height

   let statusbarView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: statusBarHeight))
   statusbarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
   view.addSubview(statusbarView)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set status bar color using below code and its working for me

```
self.navigationController?.SetStatusBar(StatusBarbackgroundColor: ThemeBackColor, StatusTextColor: .black)
```

Thanks
Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**,**iOS 14**,**UIKit**

**Step 1: Add Status bar style**

[image]

**Step 2: Change in Info.Plist**

Add View controller-based status bar appearance key with NO value

[image]

**Step 3: In your base view controller add this extension**

```
extension UIViewController
{
func setStatusBarColor(){
    if #available(iOS 13, *)
    {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
        let statusBarFrame = window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame
        let statusBar = UIView(frame: (statusBarFrame)!)
        statusBar.backgroundColor = .orange
        window?.addSubview(statusBar)
    } else {
        // ADD THE STATUS BAR AND SET A CUSTOM COLOR
        let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
        if statusBar.responds(to:#selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
            statusBar.backgroundColor = .orange
        }
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    }
}

}
```

**Step 4: In your view controller use this extension**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setStatusBarColor()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have derived your view controllers from a common view controller then, you can simply do it like this:

Step 1:
Add this key to your app's `info.plist` file.

[image]

Step 2:
`override` this in common view controller (or a `ParentViewController`).

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    if self is YourChildViewController {
        return .lightContent
    }
    return .default
}
```

*That's it! No more fancy things.*

Comment: `return .default` will in this case never be executed