# swift ios trying to change color of status bar on certain VC's

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

In my app I have 4 ViewController and in two of them I am changing the status bar from white to black like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
    }
```

The problem is if I switch between two ViewController that both have the code above the status bar will first change to black which is right, but then it changes to white again when entering the other ViewController.

How can I keep the status bar white on certain ViewController's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the following method in your VC's. Use .default or .lightContent to change the status bar color. I tested using Xcode 8 and swift 3:

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.default;
}
```

I created a new tabbed application with Xcode 7.3.1 and swift 2.3. I have two tabs with the classes associated FirstViewController and SecondViewController. In FirstViewController I added the following method:

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.Default;
}
```

And In the SecondViewController, I changed the background to black and I added the following method:

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
}
```

Finally, I added two buttons in the FirstViewController. One button present a controller modally and the other button present through push. When I presented the view modally the 'preferredStatusBarStyle' work but when I presented through push I need to add the following line of code:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .Black
```

Comment: This also requires adding the `View controller-based status bar appearance` key set to on/YES in project's `info.plist` file and may require a custom implementation of `- (UIViewController *)childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle;` on the application's root view controller subclass depending on the architecture of your view hierarchy

Comment: That did not work coz what @markedwardmurray said. But cant I just use ```override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default
    }``` in every VC ?

Comment: You would think but there are a lot idiosyncrasies with changing the global state of the status bar between view controllers. Using view controller based status bar appearance is more reliable. In iOS 10 the getters to override on UIViewController will actually be made into full properties. The global appearance method is from the days when an application was expected to have a single color scheme, either light or dark. It does not work well to switch it with frequency after application launch

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to override the delegate methods for preferredStatusBarStyle, you can still use:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

by removing:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
}
```

and let just let the status bar be set by whats happening in viewWillAppear. Obviously this is more prone to error, but if your navigation is relatively linear then it would be the simplest solution

Comment: Deprecated in iOS 9.0